# Add WkWebView constraints

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I added a wkwebView into a nib. I can not set the size from the wkWebView to the contentView (BlueView). The constraints from the BlueView are correct. Here my code:

thanks for helping

```
@IBOutlet weak var view: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var stopButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var skipButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var infoLabel: UILabel!

var webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero)

override func awakeFromNib() {

    webView.frame.size = CGSize(width: contentView.bounds.width, height: contentView.bounds.height)
    contentView.addSubview(webView)

    let myURL = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")
    let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
    webView.load(myRequest)

}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    xibSetup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    xibSetup()

}

func xibSetup() {
    view = loadViewFromNib()

    // use bounds not frame or it'll be offset
    view.frame = bounds

    // Make the view stretch with containing view
    view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight]

    // Adding custom subview on top of our view (over any custom drawing > see note below)
    addSubview(view)

}
 func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView! {

    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "ReCaptchaV2", bundle: bundle)
    let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView

    return view
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jp6rk.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qimVh.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set these constraints

```
override func awakeFromNib() {

   contentView.addSubview(webView)

   webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

   webView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

   webView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

   webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

   webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

  let myURL = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")

  let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)

  webView.load(myRequest)

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the constraints from the **parent view**, not from safe area. And keep only 4 constraints. So :

> trailing constraint from parent view = 0
>   bottom constraint from button = 0
>   top constraint from parent view = 0
>   left constraint from parent view = 0

Check these screenshots :

**1. Constraints :**

[image]

**2. Parent view selected in constraint :**

[image]

**3. Output :**

[image]

Comment: Have you a example for me?

Comment: Give me 5 minutes

Comment: @Sh_Khan's answer is perfectly fine.- programatic approach. My answer is based on storyboard, the approach which you mentioned.

Comment: Good to hear that.